# Replace requirejs plugin with webpack loader

Tags: javascript, requirejs, promise, webpack, deferred

In a requirejs world, I have a few AMD modules that return a promise. I don't want every consumer of these modules to have to deal with this async nature, so I built a plugin that will resolve the dependency once the promise is resolved.

ex: `define ['promise!some_promise_module'], (dep)-> ...`

This seems to be the last hold-out to moving to webpack, and I am having trouble understanding how to pull it off in a webpack world. It would seem that a loader is the compliment for requirejs plugins.

For reference, this is the requirejs plugin:

```
define [], ()->
  load: (name, req, load, config)->
    if config.isBuild
      load()
    else
      req [name], (promise)->
        promise.done (module)->
          load module
```

Is something like this possible in webpack?

Comment: Umm... something like [promise-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/promise-loader)?